# Confusing array sorting in PHP

Tags: php, sorting

What's the best way to sort this array alphabetically, by String1? The key numbering should always be numerical still.

Before:

```
Key     | String1    Int1 String2 Int2
--------------------------------------
0       | Alligator  3    Cake    7
1       | Crocodile  17   foobar  9
2       | Bear       1    test    6
3       | Aardvark   2    lolwhat 3
```

After:

```
Key     | String1    Int1 String2 Int2
--------------------------------------
0       | Aardvark   2    lolwhat 3
1       | Alligator  3    Cake    7
2       | Bear       1    test    6
3       | Crocodile  17   foobar  9
```

Essentially, I have an array which has a bunch of arrays in it, how can I sort those arrays within the first array alphabetically using a particular element?

Comment: As a side note, what language does the syntax highlighter think that is? Why are some words blue and others aren't? Is `Cake` more important than `test` or `foobar` or `lolwhat`?

Comment: Have you checked out the manual? In the user comments for `sort` there is a function that might help ya: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php#99700

Comment: I think its because Cake is capitalized

Comment: @Brad F Jacobs: It wound up with all elements having the letter "A".

Comment: It would be somewhat important to know how these are currently structured in an array, and if you can change the structure of the array. Also, if this data comes from SQL, you can sorta in the retrieving query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `usort` which lets you define a comparator callback function.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: I think uasort would be better suited, no?

Comment: I tried it in a similar implementation to their "fruit" example, every element was replaced with "A".

Comment: @Fase: uasort maintaines key/value associations, which is not important for this case where the keys are probably simply numeric values based on the order Cyclone's rows were returned from the DB, e.g..  That information can be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

You will want a compare function like the following:

```
function compare($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['String1'] < $b['String1'])
        return -1;
    if ($a['String1'] > $b['String1'])
        return 1; 

    // At this point the strings are identical and you can go into 
    // a second value to compare something else if you wish 
    if ($a['String2'] < $b['String2'])
        return -1;
    if ($a['String2'] > $b['String2'])
        return 1;

    // as long as you cover the three situations you are fine. 
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function str1cmp($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['string1'], $b['string1']);
}

usort($array, 'str1cmp');
```